# Datagrid Gem in Rails 4 returns PG:UndefinedColumn: ERROR:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datagrid, reporting

No hair left on my head (and I have had lots :) ), I have been pulling out my hair and for the life of me I can't figure this out.

I have a one to many relations between 2 tables. I have installed the Datagrid Gem for reporting. I need to get the report from one model based on the other one.

Please have a look at my code.

reports_grid.rb

```
class ReportsGrid
  include Datagrid
  scope do
      Land.includes(:estate)
  end
  filter(:estate, :enum, :select => proc { Estate.group("title").select("title").map {|c| [c.title] }})
  column(:id, :header => "Land ID")
  column(:current_stage, :header => "Stage")
  column(:price)
  column(:status)
end
```

reports_controller.rb

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @grid = ReportsGrid.new(params[:reports_grid]) do |scope|
        if params[:reports_grid].present?
            if params[:reports_grid][:estate].present?
                scope.joins(:estate).where("estates.title = ? ",params[:reports_grid][:estate]).page(params[:page])

            **# when I get the @grid.assets here all good and return correct number of rows**

            else
                scope.page(params[:page])
            end
        else
            scope.page(params[:page])
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Land.rb

```
belongs_to :estate
```

estate.rb

```
has_many :lands
```

Now when I go to /reports and try to run the filter I get the following error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column lands.estate does not exist LINE 1: ..._id" WHERE (estates.title = 'Olive Gardens' ) AND "lands"."e... ^ : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lands" INNER JOIN "estates" ON "estates"."id" = "lands"."estate_id" WHERE (estates.title = 'Olive Gardens' ) AND "lands"."estate" = 'Olive Gardens'
```

Why is the Gem tries to add `"lands"."estate" = 'Olive Gardens'` to the query when I have defined it at the instance.

Please let me know if you need me to add anything. Thank you in advance.

Edit:

This is what I have done and worked in the Filter:
I have done this:

```
filter(:estate_id, :enum,
           :select => lambda {Estate.all.map {|p| [p.title, p.id]}},
           :multiple => false,
           :include_blank => true
    ) do |value|
        self.where(:lands => {:estate_id => value})
    end
```

Do you it is a good approach? 
I guess in the scope I could say `Land.joins(:estate)` then use the `scope.all.map...` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Datagrid filter designed to filter data but not to just be by default.
If you have some reason why `estate` should not filter data by itself then add `:dummy => true` option:

```
  filter(:estate, :enum, :select => ..., :dummy => true)
```

But I'would recommend it. Do this instead and your hair will start growing instantly:

```
filter(:estate, :enum, :select => ...) do |scope, value|
  scope.joins(:estate).where("estates.title = ? ", value)
end
```

It seems obvious from documentation here:
https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/wiki/Filters#filter-block

Answer (score 0):

Try using references

```
Land.includes(:estate).references(:estates)
```